# writeValue with invalid value in custom form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

When I want to create custom form control in Angular I need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` which defines `writeValue(value:any): void` function.

Now imagine that the custom component only accepts strings which contains only numbers because of its inner working. It cannot accept nothing else as it cannot do anything meaningful with it.

Questions when someone calls `formControl.setValue()` with invalid value:

- What should be the value of that `formControl` (`null` or invalid input)?
- Should `writeValue` call `onChange` callback with `null` in case of invalid input, so that Angular knows that the value was not accepted?

Comment: I would choose null. What is the consequence for you doing that? Can your project consume such behaviour?

Comment: Calling `onChange` triggers `valueChange` and in some cases it may cause troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem. I my case I tried to set not-existing value to our select component.

I looked how native `select.value` attribute and jQuery's val function deals with this problem:

It turns out that: `el.value` returns `''` and `jEl.val()` returns `null`.
(https://codepen.io/mino123456/pen/VRGwYx)

So I think value should return `null`.

As @Ludevik points out, problem is that calling `onChange` in `writeValue` will set value to `null`, but it will also trigger `valueChange` event. This is undesirable, especially in:

```
formControl.writeValue('invalidValue', {emitEvent:false});
```

I looked in source code, and I found way to set value without triggering event.
But I must say, that it feels **really** hacked.

```
ngOnInit(): any {
  this._boundFormControl = this._injector.get(NgControl, null);
}

setControlValue(value: any): void {
  const dir = this._boundFormControl as any;
  const control = dir._parent.form.get(dir.path);
  control.setValue(value, {
    emitModelToViewChange: false,
    emitEvent: false
  });
}
```

Basic idea is get `formControl` from parent, and call `setValue` with `emitEvent: false`. I would **love** if angular would provide some better way.

Comment: you got it exactly with calling `formControl.writeValue('invalidValue', {emitEvent:false});`, that is exactly what happens in my case, i should have written it in the question. Nice idea with injecting form control to the component. I didn't figure out that i can tell angular that the value is null through `setValue` instead of calling the `onChange` callback.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts on the matter is you should not alter the form control value in your `ControlValueAccessor` if the value that came from control is invalid. The idea for `ControlValueAccessor` and custom form control is:

1. Provide a way for a user to see the value from control
2. Provide
   a way for a user to write value into control

If you change control value on your own, without user input, that goes against the paradigm of the thing.

Here's how I would do it:

1. I would provide a fallback value to be used in calculations/displayed if value is incorrect, so that there will be no errors trying to manipulate the wrong value (cannot read X of null/undefined etc. — in case you would need it for more complex types of data).
2. I would write a function that checks if value in control is compliant to the restrictions of control and if not — display an error in console, perhaps with `console.assert` as it is kind of like breaking the API contract of you custom control.

Here's my implementation of combobox in a nutshell (omitted a lot and simplified it, of course):

```
@Input()
items: ReadonlyArray<T>;

@Input()
stringify = (item: T) => !!item
 ? item.toString()
 : ''; // <- or any other conversion to string

@Input()
search: string

@Output()
searchChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

onNestedModelChange(search: string) {
  this.updateSearch(search);
}

onSelect(item: T) {
  this.onChange(item);
  this.updateSearch(this.stringify(item));
}

writeValue(value: T) {
  this.updateSearch(this.stringify(value));
}

private updateSearch(search: string) {
  this.search = search;
  this.searchChange.emit(search);
}
```

Template:

```
<input [ngModel]="search" (ngModelChange)="onNestedModelChange($event)">
<div class="dropdown">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items | filterPipe: search"
       class="option"
       (click)="onSelect(item)">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<combobox
  [formControl]="control" 
  [items]="items$ | async"
  (searchChange)="queryNewItems($event)"
></combobox>
```

This way you have a separate string input `search` which you use to fill nested `input` tag, when you write to that input — you filter all available items using some filtering pipe (say `stringify(item).indexOf(search)`). You also emit what you write through `searchChange` so you can use this input to request new items from the server if you have a lot of them and prefer to filter them on the backend.

Comment: Let me add more context. My component is a dropdown and it searches its available values when someone calls `writeValue`. User cannot do anything to write invalid value to the dropdown as he can only select from valid values. Invalid value can be only set programatically and in our case it happens when user edits other field that is connected to the dropdown and as the user types then the value is invalid at some point in time, until he finishes typing and then it should be valid. But until he finishes i would expect that the value of dropdown is null.

Comment: Then your control should be "nullable" i.e. be able to handle "null" as a valid lack of value. Then resetting it to null while it's calculated value should be fine. Since initial values for reactive forms is null you should account for that anyway.

Comment: Yea, it is nullable and it handles null well. We currently 'fixed' the problem on the other side. No component will ever send invalid value. Other component checks first if the value is valid and only then sends valid value or sends null in case of invalid value. But this puts extra effort outside our custom form control. Only problem with setting null in `writeValue` through `onChange` callback is that it is triggering `valueChanges` event and that is not desirable. @Mino described the problem well.

Comment: You should not be setting `null` in `writeValue` unless it came from a user action, like a cleaner cross icon. I've added my implementation of combobox component which seems to be something you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `ControlValueAccessor` component in question **requires** that its value be a string with the conditions you mentioned, I fail to see how anything other than throwing an exception would be an acceptable response in the case of invalid input.

If somebody is calling `formControl.SetValue()` on your `FormControl` and their input is **invalid**, they should be informed immediately. Setting the control's value to null or otherwise will only *hide* the issue and potentially cause new issues in the future (and they'll likely be hard to track down).

At the end of the day, the only people who can call this method are the developers working with the `FormControl`, unless you are creating some kind of public API, in which case I suggest providing a strongly-typed 'wrapper' method.

As for your second question of:

> Should writeValue call onChange callback with null in case of invalid input, so that Angular knows that the value was not accepted?

Well, firstly I would recommend going with my suggestion and not setting the value at all in this exceptional case. But just as a side note, you should not be calling the `onChange` callback inside of `writeValue` at all.

`WriteValue` is the method that Angular calls when you programmatically set the `FormControl` value *through `formControl.SetValue()`*. In other words, it already knows the value has changed, because it is the cause of that change.

You should be calling the `onChange` callback when you set the value through your `ControlValueAccessor` so that the Angular `FormControl` can be aware of this change and update its internal value. This should not be happening in the `writeValue` method though, as again, it is the method that Angular will call, not you.

I suspect, based on the wording of your question, that you knew this already though. But there is one other reason why you shouldn't that you might not be aware of:

Invoking the `onChange` callback inside of `writeValue` will not even make a difference, nor will it do what you think it will. [Here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83#ef5e) is an explanation for how Angular Forms setup the bindings to/from `FormControls` and `ControlValueAccessors`.

You'll see from the link that the `onChange` callback simply calls `formControl.setValue()` except with an `emitModelToViewChange: false` flag. This flag is used inside of the `formControl.setValue()` method, and when it is false (as it is in this case) no subscribers to `onChange` will be notified.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern), then angular will know that the value is invalid when the pattern does not match.

```
const numberOnlyControl = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'))
```